# create JSON objects from input stream

Tags: python, json, filestream

I am trying to read a really big file (4> GB) which has more than million records and create JSON objects from them. since file is too big I will have to stream it and create JSON objects on the go.
I am using ijson. here is my code sample.

```
import ijson

file_name = "test-json1.json"
parser = ijson.parse(open(file_name))
for prefix, event, value in parser:
    #if prefix.endswith('.Event') and event == 'map_key':
    #    print "start"
    if prefix.endswith('.Event') and event == "end_map":
        print "end" #create json object and save it to database.
```

now here I am stuck. How can I create individual JSON objects at the event == "end_map" so I can send that object to save it to database?

Comment: Please don't use java tags for python questions

Comment: What data do you have? What should the json object look like?

Comment: @TimCastelijns : sorry about that. here's how my JSON object looks :
`{ "Library": [{"Event": {   
"EventID": 1,
  "Truth": {
       "PE": 260.20 ,
       "VisE": 0.95 ,
       "CC": 1 ,
       "PDG": 14 ,
       "Mode": 1 ,
       "PhotonL": [ 0.00, 0.00 ],
       "PhotonE": [ 0.00, 0.00 ],
       "ParticlesPDG": [  ]
      },
   "NHits": 15,
   "HitList": [
      [  61, 163,   1,  9.3989 ],
      [  63, 235,   1, 12.9857 ]
      ]
   }
}
]
}`